# Can infopath do this?

Tags: infopath

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have four digit number - *NNNN*, and I need to increment it to nearest multiple of 10. So for instance if the number is 5010, the result should 5020. **But** if the number is 5016 the result should also be 5020.

by the way, this number is in sharepoint list, so in this case infopath would have to make a connection to the list to read the value, everytime it is open and then do the increment.

Any assistance would very appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: isn't this related to your other question? If you can add a calculated column in your list, then in InfoPath you can just read it as it is. No need for additional calculation in InfoPath too

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question as it is redundant now that you have solved your other similar to this

Comment: it seams like I do have to do this in infopath. when infopath opens, it needs to read the value submitted by he previous form and do this increment itself. Any pointers? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In InfoPath, the formula would be:

```
number(substring(YourField; 6; 4)) - (number(substring(YourField; 6; 4)) mod 10) + 10
```

Comment: Again this worked beautifully. You Rock!